# Texts and borders getting enlarged in the paper space?

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

How can I prevent lines and text in the paper space of Layout from getting enlarged? Interestingly, this doesn't happen in the Model. Do I need a translate parameter with Model Derivative, or is it a Viewer configuration?

Layout (incorrect lines):
[image: Layout]

Model (correct):
[image: Model]

Comment: I don't think this is on the viewer side. Could be some configuration issue that makes the Model Derivative service extract lines and text from the Layout in an unexpected way. If you wouldn't mind sharing the drawing with us via `aps (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`, I'd be happy to pass it along to the Model Derivative service engineers.

Comment: I wrote to the email you provided me several days ago and still haven't seen a response from your side.

Comment: It may take a while when the queue of support tickets gets too big. It's been two business days since my first comment so please stay tuned.